# How to dynamically set HTML id attribute at runtime in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm having trouble in generating dynamic ids using angular [interpolation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/interpolation).
For example I need to add a different id for each span of a list in order to scroll them with a click.
This is how i generate a single id:

```js
ctrl.letterScroll = function (letter) {
    var container = angular.element(document.getElementsByClassName('sci-refs-scroll'));
    var anchor = angular.element(document.getElementById(ctrl.title + '_' + letter));
    if (container && anchor && ctrl.compactAnchors[letter]) {
        container.scrollToElement(anchor, ctrl.compact ? 0 : 10, 800);
    }
};
```

```html
<div id="sci-refs-body-compact" layout="column" flex="95" class="sci-refs-scroll sci-refs-body-compact">
    <div class="dbclick-wrap" ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items | filter: ctrl.sciRefLibSearch | orderBy: 'name'">
        <div  layout-wrap layout="column"
              class="sci-refs-body-compact-entry"
              lvl-draggable="{{ctrl.draggable}}"
              data-scirefid="{{::item.id}}"
              data-scirefdescription="{{::item.name}}"
              data-scirefversion="{{::item.versionLabel}}">
            <div layout="row" class="sci-ref-entry-compact-row" flex>
                <span id="{{ctrl.title + '_' + item.compactAnchor}}"
                      class="sci-ref-entry-compact"
                      ng-if="item.compactAnchor && ctrl.compactAnchors[item.compactAnchor]"
                      flex="95">{{::item.name}}</span>
                <span class="sci-ref-entry-compact"
                      ng-if="!item.compactAnchor"
                      flex="95">{{::item.name}}</span>
                <md-icon class="sci-ref-doc-opener"
                         ng-click="ctrl.itemClickCallback({item: item})"
                         flex="5">visibility</md-icon>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The field item.anchor is generated after a REST call, sometimes the id is correctly generated, other times the part of item.anchor is undefined. I suspect this is due to the DOM being generated before the REST response arrives.
How could I solve? 
Is there a way to regenerate this id at runtime after there is a value for item.anchor?

The scrolling function I made uses the generated ids from the list to scroll. The ids have this format: "LIBRARY_a, LIBRARY_b, LIBRARY_c ..." and only the first row starting with a new letter has it (so there are not duplicated ids in the list).

Comment: have you tried `ng-attr-id` instead of `id`?

Comment: @Claies nope, I did not even know about it. There are several angular examples with the standard id. I give it a try now.

Comment: The problem is that I need to access that id for my scrolling function. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The problem is more likely a timing problem. The AngularJS framework will set the `id` attribute when the values arrive from the server, but it needs a digest cycle to do so. The scrolling function is likely searching for the `id` before the render completes. We need to know more about the scrolling function to resolve the timing problem.

Comment: Is the `<span>` element part of an `ng-repeat`? In that case you have opened an even larger can of worms.

Comment: @georgeawg Yes I'm iterating a list of items with ng-repeat="item in ctrl.items". Is there any other way to add dynamic ids? :s

Comment: At what point are you submitting the request? I'm asking because if you submit it at page load time, you should do so during the state transition so that the page doesn't load until the request is back.

Comment: This is the scrolling function, it works clicking on an anchor tag identified by a letter. The generated ids are of this type: "LIBRARY_a", "LIBRARY_b" etc..

Comment: I posted the full code where I need the dynamic id. I understand what you are suggesting, it's exactly what I wanted to obtain but I think I'm missing something important. How can I give angular more time to render the item? you mean like a $timeout wrapping the rest call?

Comment: How is `item.compactAnchor` created? Is it data that comes from the server? Or is it generated after data arrives from the server?

Comment: How is `ctrl.compactAnchor` created? How is the click generated?

Comment: The click is generated from an html anchor <a> represented by a letter of the alphabet. The function triggered reads the letter and scrolls the page to the corresponding dynamic id containing that letter. The variable ctrl.compactAnchor contains a letter, after a REST call i get the list of all documents, then parse every entry and get the first letter from the first element of a group (elements are grouped by first letter) so only the first element of each group has the dynamic id for scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

What i will do is I will put a ng-if on the  element and check if the data is back from the rest call.

ng-if will render the html only when the data is present

Comment: I already had it, I removed it from the snippet to make it simpler to read. The actual line is:
<span id="{{ctrl.title + '_' + item.compactAnchor}}" class="sci-ref-entry-compact" ng-if="item.compactAnchor" flex="95">{{::item.name}}</span>

Comment: Can you put the ng-if on the parent element like ng-if="$ctrl.Item"

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot because if item.compactAnchor is abstent I still need to populate the row of the list with a non-interactive element like this: 
<span class="sci-ref-entry-compact" ng-if="!item.compactAnchor" flex="95">{{::item.name}}</span>

Comment: hmm ok so just create a variable in the controller which gets set to true when data is there and ng-if on item.compactAnchor && $ctrl.dataIsThere

Comment: I tried several different implementations with this logic but I could not make it work at all. Still same behaviour, sometimes there is a correct id, sometimes the compactAnchor part is missing..